# How to declare a variable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have several queries in a query window in pgAdmin, many using the same value(s). Is there a way to declare a variable, `myVar` to use in query statements?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = myVar;

INSERT INTO table(user) VALUES (myVar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example:

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
   myVar VARCHAR := myValue;   
BEGIN  
   INSERT INTO table(user) VALUES (myVar);
END $$;
```